# What to do with Tag Wiki suggestions that I don't see as informative enough?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit, tag-wiki

Recently there's been some tag wiki suggestions that I don't think have enough information...but they don't have wrong or copied information either...

They have some very basic info, but nothing that would help a person recognize what the tag really means.

Should I reject these tags suggestions, or should I let them through since they aren't direct copy-pasta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what “wiki not helpful” or “excerpt not helpful” is for.

If you know enough to salvage the suggesion, click `Improve`. But otherwise, don't be afraid to `Reject`.

I guarantee you that all Stack Exchange sites get a lot of suggested tag wikis that suck. Don't be afraid of rejecting them.